# Rails 5: 'humanize' phrases that start with an accented character doesn't capitalize them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Localization is working fine, as per [the official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). However I have found that Rails' `humanize` method doesn't correctly capitalize the first character of a sentence if it's accented.

For example, if I have in **config/locales/fr.yml**:

```
fr:
  about_me: "à propos de moi"
```

... and in the view:

```
<%= t("about_me").humanize %>
```

... the output in the browser is

> à propos de moi

... whereas it should be

> A propos de moi

If I change the `à` to `a`, `humanize` works as expected.

Note that in French accents on capital letters are [sometimes omitted](https://www.thoughtco.com/french-accented-capitals-4085546) but let's leave that aside. I'd be happy with:

> À propos de moi

Do I just need to hardcode the capital letters in the YAML files to work around this? Naturally I'd prefer not to resort to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it in the YAML, capitalization depends on the language and the context; for example, German capitalizes all nouns but English only capitalizes proper nouns and the accent issue in French that you're already aware of, the relationship between `ß` and `SS` in German, etc. Getting things right though simple-minded string manipulation is very error prone. You're better off treating human-readable strings as opaque and immutable pieces of data that you pull out of your I18N/L10N string database and give to the user as-is.

This is more work but being correct is sort of important.

Comment: Hehe. Yes - just ran into the capitalization of names issue in the interim. I'll work on doing it this way.